# Office.context.mailbox.item.subject.getAsync is not a function

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Requirement:
Get email subject from outlook inbox by outlook add-in API.

Environment:

1. Outlook add-in (sideload)
2. "Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"
3. Visual studio code

Code:

```
async function ReadEmailSubject() {
  document.getElementById("email-subject").innerText = ""; 
  Office.context.mailbox.item.subject.getAsync(function (result) {
    var emailSubjectDiv = document.getElementById("email-subject");
    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {

        var emailSubject = result.value;
        emailSubjectDiv.innerText = emailSubject;
    } else {

        console.error("Failed to get email subject: " + result.error.message);
        emailSubjectDiv.innerText = "Failed to get email body: " + result.error.message;
    }
  });
}
```

Debug console:

```
TypeError: Office.context.mailbox.item.subject.getAsync is not a function
    at _callee2$ (e:\office-add-ins\Outlook\yo-main\Outlook Add-in\src\taskpane\taskpane.js:28:39)
    at tryCatch (e:\office-add-ins\Outlook\yo-main\Outlook Add-in\src\taskpane\taskpane.js:2:1)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (e:\office-add-ins\Outlook\yo-main\Outlook Add-in\src\taskpane\taskpane.js:2:1)
    at Generator.next (e:\office-add-ins\Outlook\yo-main\Outlook Add-in\src\taskpane\taskpane.js:2:1)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (e:\office-add-ins\Outlook\yo-main\Outlook Add-in\src\taskpane\taskpane.js:2:1)
    at _next (e:\office-add-ins\Outlook\yo-main\Outlook Add-in\src\taskpane\taskpane.js:2:1)
    at e:\office-add-ins\Outlook\yo-main\Outlook Add-in\src\taskpane\taskpane.js:2:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at e:\office-add-ins\Outlook\yo-main\Outlook Add-in\src\taskpane\taskpane.js:2:1
    at _ReadEmailSubject (https://localhost:3000/taskpane.js:266:28) {stack: 'TypeError: Office.context.mailbox.item.subjec…t (https://localhost:3000/taskpane.js:266:28)', message: 'Office.context.mailbox.item.subject.getAsync is not a function'}
```

What I have tried:

1. change "Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"
2. use "Office.context.mailbox.item.subject.getAsync({asyncContext: "Getting email subject" },function (result){...})"
   The error still appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API is available in compose scenarios only. You will get this error if you try to use this API in read scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where and when the `ReadEmailSubject` is called in the add-in. But the following code works fine on my machine in Outlook for Desktop:

```
let item;

Office.initialize = function () {
    item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    // Checks for the DOM to load using the jQuery ready method.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // After the DOM is loaded, app-specific code can run.
        // Get the subject of the item being composed.
        getSubject();
    });
}

// Get the subject of the item that the user is composing.
function getSubject() {
    item.subject.getAsync(
        function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                write(asyncResult.error.message);
            }
            else {
                // Successfully got the subject, display it.
                write ('The subject is: ' + asyncResult.value);
            }
        });
}

// Write to a div with id='message' on the page.
function write(message){
    document.getElementById('message').innerText += message; 
}
```

You can find a bunch of sample Outlook add-ins to verify what is wrong with your code, for example, see https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/outlook-verify-sensitivity-label .